# vb.NET pull text from webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I need a method so that I can check for a certain selection of keywords(i.e. "The great cake") out of any website? Is there a method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Comment: Thats a bit vague, any thing else you can do to help me

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `WebRequest` class. You can create an instance of the class passing in your URL, then parse the `WebResponse`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create(v=vs.71).aspx